# Pin 13: Do I need a Resistor?

Tags: arduino, hardware, pins

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66987/is-there-any-difference-between-pin-13-and-the-rest-of-the-pins) mentioned that pin 13 has a built-in resistor for the LED that comes standard on most Arduino units.  A friend of mine told me that because there's already a resistor on the pin, I don't have to put one on when I plug an external LED into the pin.

This doesn't sit right with me, as I read all over the place that it's ***very bad*** to plug in an LED without a current-limiting resistor.  I can't find where pin 13 is on the circuit diagram (still getting used to reading those), so I don't know how the built-in resistor is wired.

**Question-in-short:** Do I need a current-limiting resistor when using pin 13 for a (small) LED?

**EDIT**: As Polar pointed out below, a single resistor would do the trick.  However, I'm really curious as to the positioning of this single (built-in) resistor.  If it's in series with the header for P13, then it should limit current.  If it's in parallel, I don't think so.  However, my electronics knowledge isn't that vast, so I could be mistaken...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you examine the schematics for any of the Arduino boards (other than the Arduino NG Revision C, which does not have an on-board user LED), e.g. the one for the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf), the pin has a resistor and then the LED wired off it to ground, in parallel to the actual output pin header.

[image: Crop from schematic]

Thus, if you do not use a separate resistor in series to *your* own LED, there is a fair chance of damaging your LED.

Thus, yes you do need a resistor for your external LED.

Comment: nice diagram usage!

Comment: I hooked it up to a multimeter, no load, and it read 4.93v, no load. That is weird. The Arduino site also has a resistor. I had a book that said it was okay to do it just with pin 13. Never knew that. Oops. I am going to retry with  a LED hooked up tomorrow.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson - 4.93V sounds about right. Incidentally, you *do* have a load - the built in resistor. Measure the 5V output while you're at it. Most voltage regulators are typically only specified to be within 1-5% (it depends on the specific part) of the voltage they're specified for.

Comment: please note the latest UNO (R3) use a transitor to light up the led, so new user wont get strange result while using the pin for read/write

Answer (score 10):

Only the very early boards had a resistor on pin 13.  The numerous tutorials out that there that still claim pin 13 has a resistor are just flat out wrong.  *No recent (well over 2 years now) Arduino has a built-in resistor on Pin 13.*

> Question-in-short: Do I need a current-limiting resistor when using
>   pin 13 for a (small) LED?

*ALL* LEDs, regardless of size, require some form of current limiting.  When the forward voltage of the LED is applied, it turns into a short circuit.  A LED *only* drops its forward voltage.  So if the forward voltage is 3volts and the I/O pin or supply provides 5volts, something else needs to drop the remaining 2volts.

A *series* resistor will drop the rest of the supply (or pin) voltage and limit the current running through the LED.

For higher power LEDs you would probably want to use a constant current supply so that the series resistor isn't just wasting power.

Comment: All Uno R3's had an on board LED with a resistor. All Nanos and Pro Minis also have an on board led with a resistor. Even the clones. There are also resistors on Tx and Rx LEDs. Even in 2013.

You coud also drive a LED without a resistor from the reset pin on the reset as well if you (were brave enough to) make it I/O and have a high voltage programmer to recover.

Comment: @mckenzm Yes, there are resistors for the ONBOARD LEDs. The external pins do not have a series resistor. So if you connect an external LED to pin 13 (or any other pin), you must include a current limiting resistor.